# destroy() called in ngOnDestroy throws Cannot read property 'forExport' of undefined

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have a Highcharts in Angular7 app.

When I try to kill a pie chart by calling destroy() in ngOnDestroy it throws
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forExport' of undefined
  at a.Chart.destroy (highcharts.js:293)

Package.json

```
    "@angular/core": "7.2.12",
    "highcharts": "7.1.1",
    "highcharts-angular": "2.4.0",
```

HTML

```
<highcharts-chart
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
  [options]="chartOptions"
  [update]="false"
  [runOutsideAngular]="true"
  style="width: 300px; height: 280px; display: block;"
></highcharts-chart>
```

Typescript

```
export class MyChartComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  public Highcharts = Highcharts; // required
  private chartRef;

  public chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false,
      type: 'pie',
      events: this.getHighchartsEvents()
    },
    // [...]
  }

  private getHighchartsEvents() {
    const self = this;
    return {
      load: function(event) {
        self.chartRef = this;
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if(this.chartRef) {
      this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        this.chartRef.destroy();
        // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forExport' of undefined
        // at a.Chart.destroy (highcharts.js:293)
      });
    }
  }
```

Sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/4r4zm77lm4

If chart is destroyed by `do Destroy` button (which is within component with chart) it works fine.

When chart is destroyed by removing  component through setting chartVisible to false (by 'Hide' button) then ngOnDestroy is executed which .destroy() to throw an error.

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you reproduce it in an onilne code editor like codesandbox?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel - I've added a full example in sandbox above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because `highcharts-angular` wrapper destroys the chart itself. Check here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/blob/master/highcharts-angular/src/lib/highcharts-chart.component.ts#L62-L67

So you are trying to destroy it after it's destroyed.

**Wrapper code with destroy:**

```
  ngOnDestroy() { // #44
    if (this.chart) {  // #56
      this.chart.destroy();
      this.chart = null;
    }
  }
```